# Raster standard deviation stretch Python script

Tags: python, raster, arcpy, stretch

I am looking for ways of applying a permanent standard deviation stretch to rasters via a Python script.

Are there any ArcPy raster stretch functions? I was looking for a reference but could not find any.

Are there any other Python libraries that can perform the stretch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make large changes to your raster, look at [Raster Functions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Editing_function_chains_in_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000045000000/). What I'd recommend is initially creating the stretch you'd like to apply using the raster function tools, and then saving that to a template (`.rft.xml`). From there, you should be able to use `EditRasterFunction_Management` ([docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000163000000)) to apply the template to new rasters. The XML files aren't too complicated, and can be parsed with `lxml` or equivalent, if you need to programmatically manipulate the function template.

Once you're done applying the functions you need, you can just use `CopyRaster_management` to pull out the modified result into its own layer -- function chains are primarily intended for on the fly raster operations, and this step is needed to make the changes directly to the pixel values.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, however I need to permanently stretch an image (which is an image rather than raster DTM) and save it as a new standard deviation stretch image- basically enhance an image.

Comment: @meryloo: I've rewritten my answer to match your true question -- I hadn't initially realized what you were intending to do.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and help! - this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the useful PyStretch python library [[jlaura](https://github.com/jlaura/PyStretch)] that provides functions for different image stretch, such as standard deviation, percent clip, histogram equalize + common image filtering functions.

Please find the resources under the following links:

[download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStretch/0.1.2)

[user manual](https://pythonhosted.org/PyStretch/manual.html)

[usage examples](http://pythonhosted.org/PyStretch/examples.html)

Hope it may be useful for you as well!

Meryloo